# Does experience gained by working as a consultant to a Fortune 500 company count?

Tags: resume, contracting, consultants

I started my career in a Fortune 500 company and then quit my job after 3 years and made a career change from manufacturing to IT software development.

But I have joined a not so famous company which is a consultant to a fortune 500 company and I'm working in Fortune 500 company as a contract employee.

Does my experience in this company helps me in building my career?

Is there a danger of not getting job as permanent employee to larger firms?

Comment: Yes, it counts. Relax.

Comment: @David K Thanks I'm putting all my efforts in my job. The fear that all my efforts goes vain brings a lot of sleepless nights.

Answer (score 3):

> **Does my experience in this company helps me in building my career?**

It does, I'd consider it fairly equivalent in terms of experience to that of an employee. Your resume should reflect both the consulting firm you were working for and the client firm - and I'll assert that most hiring managers will consider the experience to be from the client firm.

> **Is there a danger of not getting job as permanent employee to larger firms ?**

It may cause you to appear less likely to want to become an employee. Contracting can be a foot in the door, but depending on the position, the firm may prefer a candidate that is an employee from a similar firm.

Don't panic, though. There are a lot of contract positions out there. Contracting is an opportunity to demonstrate the kind of work that you do, and if the firm likes your work, they may offer to convert you to being a full time employee. I know they do, this happened to me, and I've seen it done with others.

If you're worried about what to do next, start fishing for your next position now, don't wait until you're thirsty to dig your well.

Comment: 's Yeah my manager had also informally told me that he would push my name for a permanent position, still I get restless coz of the very thought that I can be fired for no reason anytime. Anyway thanks a lot for giving me hope.

Answer (score 0):

> Does my experience in this company helps me in building my career?

Yes, working as a consultant/contractor to large companies does help.  When you list the experience, be sure to note that you were working as a contractor for the large firm, and note the name of the smaller firm.

> Is there a danger of not getting job as permanent employee to larger
>   firms?

No.  The main danger of contracting is the "feast or famine" lifestyle.  You can be out of work for a couple of months pretty easily, so you need to plan ahead for that.  Also be sure to stay in touch with managers you've impressed so when you decide to get full-time position, they can write you a nice recommendation letter.